# boost::optional vs boost::make_optional

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

I would like to understand better the difference between creating a *boost::optional* object using the *default* constructor:

```
boost::optional<PastaType> pasta = boost::optional<PastaType>(spaghetti)
```

or using the *make_optional* version:

```
boost::optional<PastaType> pasta = boost::make_optional<PastaType>(spaghetti)
```

Looking around I just understoood that with the *make_optional* version PastaType cannot be a reference type, but I would like to figure out better when to use one or the other.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I didn't know you could use make_optional without specifying the type. 

Two others related questions came up in my mind. What's the point of using make_optional specifying the template parameter? And why spaghetti has to be of const type?

Comment: There isn't much point in using `make_optional` if you specify the template parameters. I think you are mistaken about `const`. It either copies or moves it's argument, depending on the value category of the expression

Comment: _"Two others related questions came up in my mind."_ The comments section is not a good place for asking a new question.  Consider marking one of these answers correct (it seems that you accept them) and ask a question [in the usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: 1) I can't think of any reason except if deduction would fail otherwise. If you use C++17 or later you can probably skip `make_optional`. 2) What do you mean by "_has to be `const`_"?

Comment: Thank you all! Sorry for making an improper use of the comment session; I thought keeping all together would have helped future readers.

Anyway I was wrong with the _const_ assumption; I have better explained my doubt in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916031/boostmake-optional-with-type-specification) new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make_optional` is a convenience or helper function that can reduce the amount of code you have to write by inferring the template parameter of `optional`. Functionally the two methods are equivalent.

```cpp
auto pasta = boost::make_optional(spaghetti);
```

Answer (score 4):

Prior to C++17, you couldn't deduce template arguments for a class from it's initialisation, like you could with a function template call.

As a workaround, functions named in the form `make_thing` that constructed a `thing` allowed deduction.

```
auto pasta = boost::make_optional(spaghetti); // pasta is boost::optional<PastaType>

auto pasta = boost::optional(spaghetti); // compile error before C++17, afterward pasta is boost::optional<PastaType>
```

Comment: `make_thing` is still useful for `thing<thing<T>>`, as `thing{some_thing}` use copy constructor, whereas `make_thing(some_thing);` really return `thing<thing<..>>`.