# boost::make_optional with type specification

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

I'm puzzled about the *boost::make_optional()* behavior when used with the template specification.

In particular, it's still unclear to me why this:

```
int pizza = 5;
boost::optional<int> pizza_opt = boost::make_optional<int>(pizza)
```

throws the compile error **cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’**; while this:

```
int foo(int bar)
{ return bar; }

boost::optional<int> pizza_opt = boost::make_optional<int>(foo(pizza))
```

works fine.

I already know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908075/boostoptional-vs-boostmake-optional) that it does not make much sense to use *boost::make_optional* specifying the type, but I'm reading some code which does use of this structure.

Thank you!

Comment: Idea of `std::make_optional` is to let deduction happens...

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I already knew this..

Comment: *"but I'm reading some code which does use of this structure."* Those code are "wrong".

Comment: I think you are right. But it helped me learning a new feature of this language ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template parameter of `boost::make_optional` doesn't define exactly type inside optional.

This template parameter is responsible for perfect forwarding, here is simple minimal example reproducing issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void bar(T&& x)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " 
        << std::forward<T>(x) << '\n';
}

int foo(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int pizza = 5;
    bar(pizza);
    bar<int>(foo(pizza));
    // bar<int>(pizza); // same error

    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dvMWq95rG).

So when deduction is done T is `int&` for l-values and `int` for r-values.

When you pass variable you passing l-value.

When you specified type you are forcing argument to be `int &&` which do not match to `int&`.